# Windows: setting folder permissions for exactly one level of folders

Tags: windows, permissions

Here I have a folder (E:\projects, which is also shared via the network) with several hundred folders like E:\projects\project1, E:\projects\project2, E:\projects\project3.... Each of these folders contains several subfolders and files. Currently all users have full permissions on all files and folders.

I want to change it so that the folder level of e.g. E:\projects\project1 must not be deleted. The users shouldn't be allowed to delete the folder E:\projects\project1, but they should be able to do what they want with its content.

Currently I'm failing to express this to Windows' permission system. When I'm in E:\projects and deny the permission "delete" for subfolders, it does this recursively. But this is exactly what I don't want to have. Only the folder structure exactly one level below E:\projects should get this.

Does anyone have a hint for this?

=================================

In response to Thecleaner:

I'm afraid this doesn't work as intended. The user is still able to delete this folder. Currently I'm trying this solution: granting the user group the permission to "traverse folder/execute file", "list folder/read data", "read attributes", "read extended attributes" and "read permissions" - only for this folder. "Delete" and "delete subfolders and files" is denied for this group. Then I added another permission for this group which gives full access only for subfolders and files. This results in the behaviour that the users can still move the folder E:\projects\project1 to another place. But why? I don't get it...

The user is a member of the following groups in the AD:

Domänen-Benutzer, Entwicklung, EAGLE, mup_com, archive, projecte, CPUWIN_mup, MP, Remote Web Workplace Users, Benutzer von Windows SBS-Remotewebzugriff, Windows SBS-Faxbenutzer, Konten für die Windows SBS-Ordnerumleitung, All Users, Windows SBS-Linkbenutzer

Answer (score 3):

On E:\projects\project1 set the deny to only that folder and files and don't apply them to the child objects.  ie...do it on the actual folder you want set, not at the E:\projects level.

[image]

Comment: Ok, these are two good suggestions. It was my hope that I don't have to touch every subfolder manually (160+). Maybe there is a shell/Powershell way to do this?

Comment: Did you verify this works like you wanted for a single folder?  If so, I can look a getting you a PS script.  Put a screenshot of the individual folders permissions you set that works now.

Comment: I've edited my initial text - it isn't working as I expected... maybe you have an hint.

Comment: sure, let me reproduce the environment and I'll let you know.  What server OS?

Comment: It is a Windows SBS 2011 Standard. Tomorrow I can give you more details on the group memberships.

Comment: OK, can't reproduce an SBS 2011, but should be the same as a 2008 R2 environment.  I can setup a folder structure and verify.

Comment: I added the AD group memberships of the test user. Only the membership in the group "Entwickler" seems to be of relevance. What is the powershell command for getting detailed ACL settings of folders? `get-acl H:\Daten\projecte\00000___TEST__|fl` doesn't show the exact definitions.

Comment: $rootfolder = Get-ChildItem -Path \\server\share
foreach ($sharefolder in $rootfolder) {
$sharefolder.FullName
get-acl $sharefolder.FullName  | foreach {write-host "The owner is : " $_.Owner "`nNTFS Security rights : " $_.AccessToString}   
Write-Host "`n"
}

Comment: The auto-formatter seems to have broken this code snippet...

Comment: Sorry, it is a script.   Do you have time later today to work on this?  We can do it in a chat room, but I can't do it for another 3 or 4 hours.

Comment: During the next hours I've got some time. How about you?